# useState hook renders the complete view and affects to the array data

Tags: react-native, imagepicker

**I am a total beginner to React Native.**

I'm creating a react native application. I want to capture multiple images using this application. When a user captures an image it will be stored inside an array (const tempArray = [];), likewise, all the images should be stored in it. Sametime I need to show a preview of a picture on the side of the application. For that, I'm using the react useState (const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([])) hook. Once the user captures an image it will be stored in my array, using the array I'm updating the useState hook. When the useState hook updated it will render the view again and will reset my Array with the last captured image.

I have attached my code here, please help me to find a solution. Thank you.

```
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

const tempArray = [];
const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState([]);

const chooseFile = () => {
    const options = {
        title: 'Select an option',
        storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
            path: 'images',
        },
    };

    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        // console.log('Response = ', response);
        if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker');
        } else if (response.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else {
            // let source = response;
            // You can also display the image using data:
            let source = {
                uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data
            };
            createImageArray(source);
        }
    });
};

const createImageArray = (imageData: string) => {
    console.log("stored item : " + imageData);
    tempArray.push(imageData);
    setSelectedFiles(tempArray);
    console.log("tempArray.length : " + tempArray.length);
}
```

UI should be like this,

[image]

Comment: so your goal is to when the user selects all images you have to show last image from that array.

Comment: No, I want to get all the images from that array. But what I noticed, once I added a new item to the array useState re-render the view. That will affect the previous items in the array (previous items will be replaced by new item).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that can help you. the scenario is that I am getting images from local storage and then push them to the array.

```
 const [images , setImages] = useState([])
 let image_array = data.filter((elem, index) =>elem.endsWith('.jpg')) // here i am getting imaegs fom an array by filtering . you didn't need this. after you get an images just push that to the array
          let temp_image_array = []
          image.forEach((child) =>{
             temp_image_array.push({
                 name:child // Here child is the uri of image 
             })
          })
          setImages(i_items);  // after that you can update your status.
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should convert the images to base64 and then display them like:

```
<Image
  source={{
    uri: 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
  }}
/>
```

[Example from ReactNative docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image)